# App ID does not match domain Facebook like button error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, app-id

I've been going around this site and the facebook developers form for a while and I haven't been able to find a solution to a problem I'm having.

The Facebook Like Button is not accepting a "Like" on the first click, it takes two clicks or sometimes even more to finally make that button stay liked.

I've checked my meta tags and they are as follow:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Home">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Awesome Site">
<meta id="ctl00_fbimage" property="og:image" content="http://www.myawesomedomain.com/images/sampleimage.gif">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789987">
```

Of course, the domains etc are from the site I'm working on.

I went to my APP Settings and set the domains correctly however I get this error when I run the URL Linter on facebook:

> The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://www.myawesomedomain.com/.

In my settings of my app i have the following for Site URL: `http://www.myawesomedomain.com` and for my Site Domain i have: `myawesomedomain.com`

I don't understand why is throwing me that error. Is there something wrong that I'm doing?

Thank you for any information you can provide and for your time :)

[EDIT]

> The answer for this question will most likely be to double check your code especially if you weren't the first one to code it. You might be surprised to what you find.

Thanks for the information i got. :)

Comment: Without knowing the specific domain and app ID in question it's hard to know, but are you sure that the page of the Like button and the contents of the <og:url> / <fb:like href.... are both on a subdomain of what's specified as the Site Domain for your app ID? If you've changed something and it hasn't taken effect, try the URL linter (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) to see exactly what Facebook is picking up when it crawls your page

Comment: hehe, sorry, is just that they don't let me share that information . But I fixed it. Apparently thsi side had an old ID on it already digging through the code i found another meta tag with the ID on it. Removed that and voilá! started working. Thanks for answering though :)